# Windows 2008 Cert Authority only issuing certificates for 10 days

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, remote-desktop-services, ad-certificate-services

I am trying to get a certificate for my Remote Desktop server on my AD. When I submit the request through the Certificate Authority snap in it generates a certificate that is only valid for a few days how can I modify this. The template that it is using

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issuing certificate authority's certificate is going to expire in 10 days. A CA cannot issue a certificate whose validity exceeds its own.